# Текстовая проверка

Tags: delphi

Как подсчитать количество строк в тексте? Как определить последнюю строку в тексте? Как сделать отступ от последней строки на n строк и вставить символ?

Comment: Что подразумевается под текстом? TMemo, TStringList, array of string/PChar, текстовый файл?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самый простой способ через объект типа *TStrings*.
Если текст в контейнере типа *TMemo*, то у него есть свойство *Lines* (*TStrings*).

- **Lines.Count** - кол-во строк.
- **Lines[Lines.Count - 1]** - последняя строка.
- **Lines.Add('строка')** - добавить новую строку в конец текста.
- **Lines.Add('')** - добавить пустую строку в конец текста.

Если текст в переменной типа *String*, то нужно создать объект *TStrings* и работать через него. Пример:

```
List := TStringList.Create;
try
  List.Text := Str; // Str - переменная с текстом
  // Теперь можно использовать все свойства и методы как описано выше для Lines
finally
  List.Free;
end;
```